# QM: time evolution and the propagator $\hat{U}(t)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

**1. Time evolution of a quantum state:**

Starting from the Schrödinger equation:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\hat{H}\Psi(x,y,z,t)$$
Where:
$$\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(x,y,z)$$
Assuming $V$ to be *time independent* then the wave equation can be written as:
$$\Psi(x,y,z,t)=\psi(x,y,z)T(t)$$
Applying separation of variables with separation constant $E$ we get the time independent Schrödinger equation:
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(x,y,z)+V(x,y,z)\psi(x,y,z)=E\psi(x,y,z)$$
And the time evolution function, if $\psi(x,y,z)$ is an energy eigenstate:
$$T(t)=T(0)e^{-i\frac{Et}{\hbar}}$$

**2. Unitary propagator:**

$$\psi(x,y,z,t)=\hat{U}(t)\psi(x,y,z,0)$$
With:
$$\hat{U}^{\dagger}\hat{U}=1$$
Inserting into the Schrödinger equation and some reworking gives:
$$\hat{U}=e^{-i\hat{H}t/\hbar}$$
But what is the meaning of this operator and what is its relation to time evolution?

Comment: From what I remind it represents the decay of the projection in an eigen state of the system. In other words the probability to find the system in the same state between two measurements in two different places. Something like <x(0)|U(t)|x'> means the probability to see <x> at time zero FOLLOWED BY <x'> at t. If I remember correctly.

Comment: In part 1, what you have written is true only when $\psi(x,y,z)$ is an energy eigenfunction. In part 2, $\psi(x,y,z,t)$ is *any* wave function. Your time evolution function $T(t) = e^{-iEt/\hbar}$ ($T(0)$ can always be chosen to be unity) is the eigenvalue of $U(t)$ on the specific eigenstate $\psi(x,y,z)$ whose energy eigenvalue is $E$. But in general, the time evolution of a wave function is much more complicated than a simple phase factor, hence you need the time evolution operator

Comment: *"what you have written is true only when $\psi(x,y,z)$is an energy eigenfunction"*. Thanks, that should have been clear to me. I've edited it in.

Comment: If there is nothing on TV,  you could watch this, http://bit.ly/2bYdc8O James Binney on time evolution and he has the complete course in pdf format,  http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/QBhome.htm

Comment: Thanks, Countie. 999 channels and never a g-damn thing on, so will watch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation of the time evolution operator $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Ht}$ is simply that given any state $\lvert\psi\rangle$ the time-dependent state
$$ \lvert \psi(t)\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Ht}\lvert \psi\rangle$$
solves the time-dependent Schrödinger equation
$$ \mathrm{i}\partial_t\lvert\psi(t)\rangle = H\lvert\psi\rangle.$$

Your solution by separation of variables implicitly assumes that your state is an *eigenstate* of the Hamiltonian with eigenvalue $E$, or equivalently an eigenstate of the time evolution operator with eigenvalue $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Et}$. These eigenstates, under suitable assumptions, form a *basis* of the state of spaces but not every solution to the Schrödinger equation is an eigenstate: It's a linear equation, so the sum of solutions is still a solution, but the sum of two solutions with different constants $E_1,E_2$ has no constant associated to it anymore.

Comment: Thanks ACM, nice answer. Any reason you dropped an $1/\hbar$ there?

Comment: @Gert I dropped it just because it's annoying and one usually works in units where $\hbar = 1$. You can add it back in without changing anything.